# How do I make variables whose values change depending on other variables?

Tags: javascript, oop

I created a 'Person' constructor :

```
function Person(firstName, secondName) {
  'use strict';
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.secondName = secondName;
  this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.secondName;
}
```

, then I created an instance of it:

```
var person1 = new Person('David', 'Johns');
```

The value of `person1.fullName` now will be `David Johns`
I tried to modify the value of `person1.firstName` into `George`

I expected the value of `person1.fullName` to change into `George Johns` but it hasn't changed!

So how do I make an object whose properties depend on other properties?
Or variables whose values depend on other variables?

Comment: The ultimate answer us that you use a property setter. *Would* I? No, there's no real reason to optimize/memoize a computed property like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a getter which uses all updated value of the variables like

```js
function Person(firstName, secondName) {
  'use strict';
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.secondName = secondName;
  this.getFullName = () => this.firstName + ' ' + this.secondName;
}

let p = new Person('Hello', 'World');

console.log(p.getFullName());

p.firstName = 'Hi';

console.log(p.getFullName());
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is assigned ones what you should try is to make a getter that returns the current one with a method like so.

```
function getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.secondName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In oop for such instances you can use a separate method than an attribute. Think all depending attributes as methods.
For your question it would be as,

```
function Person(firstName, secondName) {
  'use strict';
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.secondName = secondName;
  this.getFullName = function(){return this.firstName + ' ' + this.secondName};
}
```